# Python requests.get() hangs on 'https://www.adidas.com'

Tags: python

I'm trying to open pages from 'https://www.adidas.com' with python requests.get(). But the script hungs. The problem was found only in this domain. I can't find the reason. For other urls script works fine.

I've tried to set up timeout and exception to find out the problem, but couldn't find the clue.

```
import requests


shop_link = 'https://www.adidas.com'
try:
    res = requests.get(shop_link, timeout=5)
    print(res.text)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

I expect the text of the page but the actual output is timeout error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.adidas.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

If I don't use timeout at all the script hangs.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    res = requests.get(shop_link)
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/oleh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1346, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1012, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 874, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Add a user-agent header. ```requests.get(shop_link, timeout=10, headers={"User-Agent": "Python"})```

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Thank you. Your solution helped. SOLVED.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon your solution works well when I run the script from my computer. But when I deployed the script on Heroku it hangs on the same place again.

Comment: Does heroku allow outgoing requests?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon I think yes. It works well with another domain (for example "https://www.reebok.co.uk"). But request from 'www.adidas.com' hungs.